# Inner Join x Exists - is there a difference

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables on a MySQL database:

```
mysql> select * from employee;
+------+---------+
| id   | name    |
+------+---------+
|    2 | Olavo   |
|    3 | Ricardo |
|    1 | Ricardo |
+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from works_for;
+-------------+--------------+
| employee_no | company_name |
+-------------+--------------+
|           2 | Luz          |
|           1 | Vale         |
+-------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I need to know if there is a difference between these two queries. In which case should I use each one?

```
select e.name
from employee e inner join
     works_for w
     on (e.id=w.employee_no);

select e.name
from employee e
where exists (select 1 from works_for w where w.employee_no=e.id);
```

Comment: Check the execution plan. They might actually be equivalent in this contrived case.

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference.  If multiple rows in `works_for` match a particular row in `employee`, then the `inner join` returns multiple rows.  The `exists` only returns one row.

Because of this difference, the two queries might have quite different execution paths and timing.  Such differences would show up on much larger tables than in your example.

However, in practice, the difference in performance is not significant.  Both can take advantage of underlying indexes and table statistics.  So, the choice of which to use is in many cases just a matter of style.

Because you are only selecting rows from the first table, my preference is to use `exists`.

Answer (score 0):

Both the queries provides you the same result.

1. `Join` provides you the functionality to fetch data from both the tables. Try below query to understand.

   ```
   select *
   from employee e inner join
    works_for w
    on (e.id=w.employee_no);
   ```
2. `EXISTS or IN` condition can be use or a subquery to check if the data from the main table is available in the table provided in the sub query. Irrespective of `Join`,  it fetched you the records from main table alone. Try below query to understand

   ```
      select *
      from employee e
      where exists (select 1 from works_for w where w.employee_no=e.id);
   ```

Also using `Join` or a `Subquery` depends on your requirements and query performance. `Join` gives you good performance compared to a subquery.